# Usefull to unset $q->queryBuilder() for memory reasons?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

is it general usefull to unset the following Query to have more memory? Or ist $q to be saved as a query in the cache?

```
$repository = $em->getRepository('Some:Entity');
    $q = $repository->createQueryBuilder('rep')
            ...
            ->getQuery();
   $result = $q->getResult();

unset($q); // is it usefull or not?
unset($repository);  // also usefull?
```

Comment: Though not entirely sure, I think you can do it for the memory. But from previous projects I haven't unset the query or repository. And noticed barely any problems memory wise.

Comment: Don't unset the repository.  The manager maintains an internal list of repositories so trying to unset it will either have no effect or unpredictable effects.  And unless you have some long running process which creates hundreds of query builders then unsetting the query builder is not going to have any noticeable effect.